# sudo amdgpu-install command not found

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

WSL2.
I'm trying to install ROCm and failing miserably, my current try using AMD's official guide gets me stuck here,
after:

```
sudo apt-get update
wget https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install/5.4.3/ubuntu/jammy/amdgpu-install_5.4.50403-1_all.deb 
sudo apt-get install ./amdgpu-install_5.4.50403-1_all.deb
```

I then need to run:

```
sudo amdgpu-install --usecase=rocm
```

which gives me `command not found`
I'm running this in home/user which should be in the PATH, right? Other posts I searched recommended that.

Link just in case: https://docs.amd.com/bundle/ROCm-Installation-Guide-v5.4.3/page/How_to_Install_ROCm.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  As far as I know, ROCm isn't supported *directly* under WSL since there's no direct access to the GPU (or even drivers).  However, WSL does provide some access to GPU-compute tasks through the *Windows* drives.  What is your end goal with ROCm?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds
Thank you! I've been trying for a while, reset wsl 5x+ already and couldn't install, maybe that's why? I'm no programmer, just want to run a version of this, https://github.com/openai/whisper on my GPU for language learning.